# Can you explain in what way do the distributive pronoun in the following sentences stand alone?

Tags: questions, nouns, distributives

rule: You can use distributive pronouns as a stand alone or by themselves.  In what way does the distributive pronoun stand alone in the following sentences? Does this mean they stand alone without a noun following them or in what way do these distributives pronouns stand alone?

Did you do [ **that**]?
I'd like to buy [**these**].
Which of [**those**] would you like?

Comment: Do you understand the term "stand alone"? That is maybe what you need to look up.

Comment: I've just searched both the Internet and Google Books for "Distributive pronoun". The vast majority of matches from *both* sources seem to be low-quality text (from non-native Anglophones) intended as [TEFL](https://www.internationalteflacademy.com/blog/what-is-tefl-and-what-is-tefl-certification) resources. From what I can see, "distributive pronouns" means words like ***each, either, neither, any, no-one*** and ***none*** (they're *singular* pronouns that can be used to refer to ***one*** of a group). But ***that, these, those*** aren't "distributive" - they're ***demonstrative pronouns***.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear: is part of this question a quote from another source? To be honest, I'm confused by "... as a stand alone or by themselves." Doesn't that mean the same thing? Also, "that," "these" and "those" are not what I would call [distributive pronouns](https://www.teachingbanyan.com/grammar/distributive-pronoun/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers (In fairness, I didn't have a ready answer either and Googled it. I'm not sure that it's an [invalid linguistic concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_pronoun), though.

Comment: Also, a bit of a red herring, but "stand-alone" is more often found in [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stand-alone) as an adjective, not a noun (though note that link has some noun examples), and either hyphenated or combined into "standalone."

Comment: ...but yes, demonstrative pronouns (pronouns denoting things you could in principle "point to") can certainly be used without an explicit noun following. So ***I did that*** and ***I did that thing*** are in most cases semantically equivalent - it's just a ***stylistic choice*** whether to include an actual noun (such as ***thing, feat, deed***, there).

Comment: ...AND the same applies with ***each, either, neither,...***, regardless of whether you call them "demonstrative" or "distributive" pronouns. So ***John or James can fix this. Either is quite capable*** is fine with no explicit noun after "either". But it would *also* be fine there to have *Either **person** is quite capable*.

Comment: The words you cite are not distributives, which in any case are not pronouns but the determinatives "each" and "every". In your examples, they are demonstrative determinatives. These can have both dependent and independent uses, for example: "This milk is stale" (dependent) / "That is not true" (independent). In the dependent use they function as pre-head determiner or degree modifier; in the independent use they function as fused determiner-head in noun phrase structure.

Comment: The demonstratives are primarily deictic, referring to objects or events present in the situation of utterance, but they can also be anaphoric. In your examples, “these” is probably deictic; in the others “that” and “those” could be either deictic or anaphoric depending on context.